# custom NSViewController never receives windowDidLoad when used within plugin

Tags: cocoa, macros

Using Xcode 7.3 on MacOS 10.11, objective C.

My custom class, IsoDate, has an xib with a view containing NSText and NSStepper.
In a test application this code:

```
_dateViewControllerM = [[IsoDate alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[_dateViewControllerM view];
```

behaves as documented. E.g.,in isoDate.m, a breakpoint on:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { ...
```

is caught as soon as the view method is invoked. Now to do the same thing within a plugin, I have to reference the plugin bundle instead of mainBundle, so:

```
_dateViewControllerM = [[IsoDate alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:thePluginBundle];
```

But now the - (void)windowDidLoad  is never called. Even if I use loadView, it still is not called. I am able to work around the problem by explicitly calling some initialization, and the subsequent code to addSubview etc. all works as expected.

But why?? - what is it that makes the invocation of "view" within the plugin different from the invocation within the test program?

Comment: If you override `-viewDidLoad` do you see different results?  Only mention because you said `IsoDate` is a `NSViewController` subclass

Comment: thanks for catching my typo - it is in fact viewDidLoad that I am over-riding and that is where my breakpoint is. Breakpoint is caught when the IsoDate is used in my test program, but it is not caught when IsoDate is used in a plugin. Other than that, the IsoDate class works as expected (accepts a date string in iso format, checks validity, etc) in both environments.

Comment: It would appear to me that the view just fails to load? Do you see it from within your plugin?

Comment: Yes, the custom NSViewController is loaded from the xib - it appears in the plugin just the same as it appears in the test application. But in the test application the initialization (setting an NSString to @"" instead of nil) happens in the viewDidLoad. In the plugin, viewDidLoad is never called so I have to do that initialization after allocating. From then on, everything works the same in the test application or in the plugin.

Comment: That is definitely weird that the view shows, but `-viewDidLoad` doesn't get called.  Have you tried `-viewDidAppear`?

Comment: Following your suggestion, I added -viewDidAppear to my isoDate.m.   As expected in my test program, debug breakpoints show first viewDidLoad is called, and then viewDidAppear.  But with the class loaded into the plugin (the plugin is for adding functionality to Daylite from Marketcircle), these same breakpoints are never hit.

Comment: Oh wait a minute. Is your plugin a separate process?  Try putting NSLogs in there, and then checking macOS Console to see if anything comes out?

Comment: ok. Tried that. No luck - no log output to the debugger, nor to the console. As before `- viewDidLoad` works as expected in test application, but not in plugin.